# Smoothing grid of cells inSrcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I have a grid of cells that outline sharp transitions between different neighbour values:

[image]

I would like to "smooth" the transition between the cells so that I obtain some sort of gradients between the different values.

How can I do it with ArcGIS?

Comment: A google on "ArcGIS smoothing" returned http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/smooth-polygon.htm  You'll need to convert to polygon first.

Comment: Are you sure the "sharp" transitions originate in the data? Can you make it appear like a gradient playing with  its symbology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `focal statistics` function in your `spatial analyst` toolbox. You find the documentation of the function in your ArcGIS desktop help, or under [this link](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/focal-statistics.htm).

Focal statistics will go through your grid using the radius or neighbourhood you've defined and will then apply the selected statistics to each cell. I would recommend using `mean` for your task, since it will smooth out the boundaries between your sharp breaks. Also check the screenshot below. **Note** that this function will increase the size of your raster by the size of your chosen neighbourhood (since it also treats the cells on the edges). You might have to clip it to your original extent afterwards.

[image: focalstats]